# Swagger-editor running locally shows empty page

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I am new to swagger.

I have created APIs in django-rest-framework. I want to document them. Hence reading about swagger.

I tried django-rest-swagger but because of lack of documentation I could not make my code suitable for documentation.
Hence I am trying swagger editor which will allow me to design API structure from scratch. I have installed it locally but it is showing me empty page at "127.0.0.1:9000". what should I do now ?

I want to write YAML or JSON file that will be consumed by swagger-editor installed locally. How can I achieve this ?

This is the error on console when I load 127.0.0.1:9000

```
Warn: could not find module util
http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular-schema-form/dist/schema-form.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
angular.js:80 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'schemaForm' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/$injector/nomod?p0=schemaForm
angular.js:80 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module PhonicsApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module schemaForm due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'schemaForm' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Comment: A few comments: Swagger-editor does not consume YAML/JSON, it produces it. Also, if you have any issues with the editor, it's better to open an issue directly on the repository. Lastly, you can use the online editor for now at http://editor.swagger.io.

Comment: yeah, online editor is a solution but is there any way so that I can do documentation on my staging server because I need to expose it to third party.. any suggestions ?

Comment: Even if you use the editor locally, you'd need to export the JSON and host it somewhere, so those two are unrelated.

Comment: I think I will go with online editor for now, thanks for your time @Ron

Comment: It seems you get empty JSON {} from your local server. Check it.

Comment: Nope, I am facing errors in console. As I shown in question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what is the problem here. As a general note, you can always clean up npm and Bower modules and start from clean state again.

```
npm cache clean
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
bower cache clean 
rm -rf app/bower_components
bower install
npm start
```

Comment: thanks for your time, currently not in a position to test this code but yeah surely I will try.

Comment: same here still empty page. blank and white. Tried your solution but still, blank. Any ideas? and bower install says "bower ENOENT        No bower.json present"

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem. 
Previously my node version was the latest v6 
I reinstalled everything and then install v4.4.4

```
node --v
```

make sure it's v4.4.4

```
npm install -g http-server

wget https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/releases/download/v2.10.1/swagger-editor.zip

unzip swagger-editor.zip

http-server
```

don't use http-server swagger-editor